# Lost in a sea of nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is supposed to duplicate a form and clear it out. It's clearing everything except checkboxes. Why is this? http://jsfiddle.net/GM2GN/1/

```
    function addForm(btn, prefix) {
            var formCount = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
            // You can only submit a maximum of 10 todo items 
            if (formCount < 100) {
                // Clone a form (without event handlers) from the first form
                var row = $(".item:first").clone(false).get(0);
                // Insert it after the last form
                $(row).removeAttr('id').hide().insertAfter(".item:last").slideDown(300);

                // Remove the bits we don't want in the new row/form
                // e.g. error messages
                $(".errorlist", row).remove();
                $(row).children().removeClass("error");

                // Relabel or rename all the relevant bits
                $(row).children().children().children().children().each(function () {
                    updateElementIndex(this, prefix, formCount);
                    $(this).val("");
                });

                // Add an event handler for the delete item/form link 
                $(row).find(".delete").click(function () {
                    return deleteForm(this, prefix);
                });
                // Update the total form count
                $("#id_" + prefix + "-TOTAL_FORMS").val(formCount + 1);
            } // End if
            else {
                alert("Sorry, you can only enter a maximum of 100 items.");
            }
            return false;
        }
        // Register the click event handlers
        $("#add").click(function () {
            return addForm(this, "form");
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different from other input elements like text input, changing the checkbox value does not change the 'checked' status. The val() only change the value of the checkbox that submits to server. to change the checked status:

```
checkBoxes.prop("checked", false);
```

Comment: Thank you! I also saw "type = text" condition in delete function and changed that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Above is the complete modified code..

just check if the actual input you're resetting is a checkbox, in that case, $(this).val('') will set its value to an empty string, yet this does not remove it's "checked" property.

I've just added this check after `$(this).val('') :`

```
if ($(this).is('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
    $(this).removeAttr("checked");
}
```

modified code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            // Code adapted from http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1389/  
            function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
                var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+-)');
                var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx + '-';
                if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex,
                replacement));
                if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
                if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);
            }

        function deleteForm(btn, prefix) {
            var formCount = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
            if (formCount > 1) {

                $(btn).parents('.item').remove();            

                var forms = $('.item'); // Get all the forms  
                // Update the total number of forms (1 less than before)
                $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
                var i = 0;
                // Go through the forms and set their indices, names and IDs
                for (formCount = forms.length; i < formCount; i++) {
                    $(forms.get(i)).children().children().children().children().each(function () {
                        if ($(this).attr('type') == 'text') updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
                    });
                }
            } // End if
            else {
                alert("You have to enter at least one student!");
            }
            return false;
        }

        function addForm(btn, prefix) {
            var formCount = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
            // You can only submit a maximum of 10 todo items 
            if (formCount < 100) {
                // Clone a form (without event handlers) from the first form
                var row = $(".item:first").clone(false).get(0);
                // Insert it after the last form
                $(row).removeAttr('id').hide().insertAfter(".item:last").slideDown(300);

                // Remove the bits we don't want in the new row/form
                // e.g. error messages
                $(".errorlist", row).remove();
                $(row).children().removeClass("error");

                // Relabel or rename all the relevant bits
                $(row).children().children().children().children().each(function () {
                    updateElementIndex(this, prefix, formCount);
                    $(this).val("");
                    if ($(this).is('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
                     $(this).removeAttr("checked");
                    }
                });

                // Add an event handler for the delete item/form link 
                $(row).find(".delete").click(function () {
                    return deleteForm(this, prefix);
                });
                // Update the total form count
                $("#id_" + prefix + "-TOTAL_FORMS").val(formCount + 1);
            } // End if
            else {
                alert("Sorry, you can only enter a maximum of 100 items.");
            }
            return false;
        }
        // Register the click event handlers
        $("#add").click(function () {
            return addForm(this, "form");
        });

        $(".delete").click(function () {
            return deleteForm(this, "form");
        });
    });
```